# DuckDuckGo Scraper, can not go to next page

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a Url scraping code that works on bing and Google and navigates fine through the pages.

I am now tring to set it to work on duckduckgo.com. I have got it working so it scrapes from a single page. The ONLY problem I have is I CAN NOT workout how to get it to show more results, how to navigate. It only pulls results from the first page.

Google and Bing have a next button which the code can navigate, however I can not work out how to do it for duckduckgo. I am stuck on this last bit. **The rest is fine.** *The search results, pages to navigate and 2x delays come from Sheet10*

**I DO NOT need the fully code re-written. All I need help on is how to navigate the pages.**

```
Private Sub duckduckgoScraper()
'''DuckDuckGo URL SCRAPER
Dim ie As Object
Dim HTMLdoc As Object
Dim nextPageElement As Object
Dim div As Object
Dim link As Object
Dim url As String
Dim pageNumber As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim myCounter As Long

'''Takes search from Sheet10 to DuckDuckGo
    url = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" & Replace(Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("G17").Value & Range("H17").Value, " ", "+")
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate url
Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop
End With

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
    Set HTMLdoc = ie.document

'''Searches URLS and places them in Sheet called Sheet2  ROW 2 Column A
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    pageNumber = 1
    i = 2
Do
    For Each div In HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("div")
        If div.getAttribute("class") = "result__body links_main links_deep" Then
            Set link = div.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = link.getAttribute("href")
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next div
            
'''Searches Number of Pages entered in Sheet10
    If pageNumber >= Replace(Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("I17").Value, " ", "+") Then Exit Do
        On Error Resume Next

'''################################################################################################
'''##########################  **I am stuck here, the rest is fine**  #############################
'''################################################################################################
        Set nextPageElement = HTMLdoc.getElementByClassName("I NEED THIS BIT, I AM STUCK HERE")
    If nextPageElement Is Nothing Then Exit Do
 
       
'''Scrolls Down the Browser
    ie.document.parentWindow.Scroll 0&, 99999
'''Random delay from Max number entered in Sheet10
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, Application.RandBetween(1, Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("J17").Value))
'''Click the next page
        nextPageElement.Click 
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
'''Random delay from Max number entered in Sheet10
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, Application.RandBetween(1, Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("K17").Value))
        Set HTMLdoc = ie.document
''' Delete duplicates
    Sheet2.Columns("A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
''' Delete Row If Blank
    Sheet2.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        pageNumber = pageNumber + 1
myCounter = myCounter + 1
Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("G6").Value = myCounter
    Loop
End With

'''Quite browser and clear
ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
    Set HTMLdoc = Nothing
    Set nextPageElement = Nothing
    Set div = Nothing
    Set link = Nothing

''' To stop the code early, change page number to 0, else code will finish when page number completed
If Sheet10.Range("I17") = 0 Then
    Complete.Show
        Termination.Hide
ElseIf Sheet10.Range("I17") > 0 Then
    Complete.Show
End If
End Sub
```

**What I have tried So Far**
I have tried the bits in yellow,however I can not get it to work. The rld-1 will change to rdl-2 and 3 when the next button is clicked. This is the only bit i am now stuck on.
[image]
[image]

Please could someone advise. I think it may be due to it being JavaScript, but I have limited knowledge in Programing and have been stuck on this for  few days now.

As always, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clicking on "More Results" button to load all the pages first. I did that using such lines

```
    Dim objMoreResults As Object, p As Long
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate url
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    End With
    p = 1
backP:
    On Error Resume Next
        Set objMoreResults = ie.document.getElementById("rld-" & p)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not objMoreResults Is Nothing Then
        objMoreResults.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
        Set objMoreResults = Nothing: p = p + 1
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3): GoTo backP
    End If
```

This is the full code that is working fine for me. Try this code first before trying to edit the lines of code to see if this code is working or not

```
Sub DuckDuckGo_Scraper()
    Dim x, ie As Object, objMoreResults As Object, htmlDoc As Object, div As Object, sURL As String, p As Long, i As Long
    x = Application.InputBox("Enter The Number Of Pages", , 2)
    If Not IsNumeric(x) Then Exit Sub
    p = 1: i = 1
    sURL = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" & Replace(Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("G17").Value & Range("H17").Value, " ", "+")
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate sURL
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
BackP:
        On Error Resume Next
            Set objMoreResults = ie.document.getElementById("rld-" & p)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not objMoreResults Is Nothing Then
            objMoreResults.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
            Set objMoreResults = Nothing: p = p + 1: If p = Val(x) Then GoTo NextP
            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3): GoTo BackP
        End If
NextP:
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)
        Set htmlDoc = .document
        For Each div In htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("result__title")
            i = i + 1
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value = div.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
        Next div
        .Quit
    End With
    Set ie = Nothing: Set htmlDoc = Nothing: Set div = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Yasser, Thanks for this. I have a rough idea how I can put this in my code, but don't want to screw anything up. Not trying to be cheeky, but could you post back with a completed code, Yours and Mine all in one. I will also try to give it a shot as that is the best way to learn. However I am not 100% confident

Comment: I am getting an error message here `objMoreResults.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click` **object variable or with block variable not set**. Originally my code allowed the user to place the NUMBER OF PAGES they wanted to scrape, this was take from Sheet10 Cell I17. I am not 100% sure if this is doing that or just pulling of ALL the results for the search item, as that could lead to X amount of pages, which may not be relevant as the user might want 6 pages and it pull of All (All being X amount). Please could you clarify this. I have tested it & it is giving more results but with the error msg.

Comment: I have used p variable as counter for the number of pages. You can add a line with a condition if p >=6 then goto specific point and resume the code processing.

Comment: **YasserKhalil** Thanks for the update, I think I have made the changes in the right place, which is **FROM** `Set objMoreResults = Nothing: p = p + 1` **To** `Set objMoreResults = Nothing: p = Replace(Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("I17").Value, " ", "+") + 1`.  I am not sure if it should be `"+")` or `"+") + 1` .  However I am still having the same above error message on this line of code `objMoreResults.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click` **object variable or with block variable not set.** Any idea WHY? Thanks for everything so far..

Comment: Hi, I think I have worked out why I am getting the error message on this line of code `objMoreResults.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click `. I think it is due to there not being enough pages to scrape e.g. I put in 10 pages and there are only 8. It trys to go to page 9 but can not and the error happens. I tried to write an IF statement, so if less that xx pages then GoTo the last bit of code and close the browser. However I could not get it to work. Could someone please help as this is the last bit I am now stuck on. Thanks

Comment: I already put this line `If Not objMoreResults Is Nothing Then` and if the object is missing then it will complete the code. The code works fine for me.

Comment: YasserKhalil, Thanks for keeping an eye on this. If you are saying it works then it must work only with your code, however when i try to put BOTH codes together yours and mine, i am getting the error. If there are more pages requested to extraction than that which can be extracted the the problem happens I was trying to come up with an IF statement like but can not work one out

Comment: I have updated the post. Try the code as it is first to check if it is working or not. Then you can edit to suit your needs.

Comment: The code works in the sence that it allows me to extract urls from the FIRST PAGE only, if that was the intention then it works for me. If the code was to extract the number of pages input into the inputbox then it does not work for me as it only pulls data from the first page, about 13 results.

Comment: As for me the code grabs all the links .. Try using F8 to follow the lines and see if "More Results" button is clicked or not? .. Increase the time of waiting from 3 seconds to 5 seconds for example ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok its not the best code in the world, but it works. BIG thanks to YasserKhalil I could not have done this with out him. I had to make changes to both codes to get it to work.
Thanks again YasserKhalil

```
Private Sub duckduckgoScraper()
'''DuckDuckGo URL SCRAPER
Dim ie As Object
Dim HTMLdoc As Object
Dim div As Object
Dim link As Object
Dim url As String
Dim i As Long
Dim myCounter As Long
Dim objMoreResults As Object
Dim p As Long

'''Takes seach from Sheet10 to google
    url = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" & Replace(Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("G17").Value & Range("H17").Value, " ", "+")
On Error Resume Next
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate url
Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop
End With

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
    Set HTMLdoc = ie.document

'''Searches URLS and places them in Sheet called Sheet2  ROW 2 Column A
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    pageNumber = 1
    i = 2

Do
    p = 1
backP:

Set objMoreResults = ie.document.getElementById("rld-" & p)
    On Error GoTo 0
''' End do in NO MORE results
   If objMoreResults Is Nothing Then Exit Do
'''If objMoreResults not same as pages requested on sheet10 I17
  If objMoreResults <> Sheet10.Range("I17").Value Then
        objMoreResults.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
  Set objMoreResults = Nothing: p = p + 1
'''Scrolls Down the Browser
    ie.document.parentWindow.Scroll 0&, 99999
'''Random delay from Max number entered in Sheet10
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, Application.RandBetween(1, Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("J17").Value))
       ' nextPageElement.Click 'next web page
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
'''Random delay from Max number entered in Sheet10
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, Application.RandBetween(1, Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("K17").Value))
    Set HTMLdoc = ie.document

    On Error Resume Next
''' extract urls
    For Each div In HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("div")
        If div.getAttribute("class") = "result__body links_main links_deep" Then
         'If div.getAttribute("class") = "result__a" Then
            Set link = div.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = link.getAttribute("href")
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next div

'''' Delete duplicates
    Sheet2.Columns("A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
'''' Delete Row If Blank
    Sheet2.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        'pageNumber = pageNumber + 1
''' Loop Counter
myCounter = myCounter + 1
    Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("G6").Value = myCounter
''' If same as Sheet10 G6 then end
If Sheet10.Range("G6").Value = Sheet10.Range("I17").Value Then Exit Do

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3):
GoTo backP
End If

Loop
End With

ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
    Set HTMLdoc = Nothing
    Set objMoreResults = Nothing
    Set div = Nothing
    Set link = Nothing

If Sheet10.Range("I17") = 0 Then
    Complete.Show
        Termination.Hide
ElseIf Sheet10.Range("I17") > 0 Then
    Complete.Show
End If
End Sub
```